# Can't retrieve data from Firebase using python-firebase over Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase

Anyone of you who have used this library before? Here's my code:

```
from firebase import firebase
import logging

class FIREBASE_API():

    def __init__(self):
        authentication = firebase.FirebaseAuthentication('MY_SECRET', 'myemail@domain.com', 'pw')
        self.firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://your_storage.firebaseio.com', authentication)

    def get_data(self, path):
        if path is not None:
            return self.firebase.get(path, None)
        return {}
```

I made sure that the secret, email, password and Firebase URL is correct but when I use the get_data method I get this:

> ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))

What could be missing?

Comment: There are actually two open source projects called python-firebase. Can you clarify which one (by linking to where you found it)?  Also, tell us about your firebase. Do you have security rules in place?

Comment: Here's the library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2. By the way I'm using Google App Engine. It seems like GAE have no subprocess module to support this library.

Comment: That's likely the cause. Google App Engine restricts a lot of stuff, including opening sockets. This requires modifications to many HTTP libraries, including the one that your python wrapper is using.  Can you try using the Firebase REST API with App Engine URL Fetch to see if it works? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/

Comment: After a little more investigation into the library (https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase/blob/master/firebase/firebase.py) I'm not sure why this isn't working based on the App Engine docs. Can you clarify your question to help with the investigation? Let's rule out App Engine issues. Can you make an unauthenticated request to an open Firebase?